# Elasticsearch now function problems

Tags: date, elasticsearch

I'm having problems trying to get a query working with the "now" function. My current query looks something like this:

```
{
     "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : [ 
                { "match": { "originCountry" : "GB" }},
                { "match": { "destinationCity" : "MIL" }}
            ]
         }
    },
    "filter" : {
        "and": {
           "filters": [
              {
                  "exists":  {"field": "dateBack"}
              } ,
              {
                  "script" : {"script" : "doc['originRegion'].value == doc['destinationRegion'].value"}
              },
              {
                 "range": {
                    "dateOut": {
                       "gte": "now"
                    }
                 }
              }
           ]
        } 
    }
}
```

That's not returning any results. However if I change the range section to a string date like:

```
 "range": {
     "dateOut": {
             "gte": "20150101"
      }
 }
```

It works perfect. In my index mapping all date fields are using the "basic_date" format (YYYYMMDD)

Could be this creating any issues for the now function? Does anyone knows how the now function works? Is it converting the "now" date to whatever date format the field being compared is using?  I'be been unable to find any useful documentation about this. 
Thanks

Comment: you are running "greater or equal" than now? how are you planning to get something in the future if has not being indexed yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your date mapping - it should be `YYYYMMdd` instead of `YYYYMMDD`

When I set up the mapping:

```
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/index/testnow/_mapping -d '
{"testnow": {
    "properties": { 
        "dateOut": {"type": "date","format" : "YYYYMMdd"}, 
        "dateBack": {"type": "date","format" : "YYYYMMdd"}
    }}}'
```

and post in a couple of docs:

```
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/index/testnow/ -d '
{
    "originCountry": "GB",
    "destinationCity": "MIL",
    "dateBack" : "20140212",
    "originRegion" : "X",
    "destinationRegion" : "X",
    "dateOut" : "20140201"
}'

curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/index/testnow/ -d '
{
    "originCountry": "GB",
    "destinationCity": "MIL",
    "dateBack" : "20150212",
    "originRegion" : "X",
    "destinationRegion" : "X",
    "dateOut" : "20150201"
}'
```

and run the query:

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/index/testnow/_search -d '
{
  "query" : {
    "filtered" : {
     "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : [ 
                { "match": { "originCountry" : "GB" }},
                { "match": { "destinationCity" : "MIL" }}
            ]
         }
    },
    "filter" : {
      "and" : [
           {"exists":  {"field": "dateBack"}},
           {"script" : {"script" : "doc[\"originRegion\"].value == doc[\"destinationRegion\"].value"}},
           {"range": {"dateOut": {"gte": "now"}}}
          ]} }}}'
```

I get back a single document as expected:

```
    {
  "took" : 11,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 1.4142135,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "index",
      "_type" : "testnow",
      "_id" : "AUqgq8u4aqAGLvfmRnfz",
      "_score" : 1.4142135,
      "_source":
{
    "originCountry": "GB",
    "destinationCity": "MIL",
    "dateBack" : "20150212",
    "originRegion" : "X",
    "destinationRegion" : "X",
    "dateOut" : "20150201"
}
    } ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Olly. Sorry, totally my fault, I trusted all date fields were correctly configured, but unfortunately dateOut wasn't, it was actually configured as string so that's why "now" wasn't working. I have recreated the mappings, and it's all working ok now. Sorry for the trouble